# Reconnecting Facebook comments to another URL

Tags: facebook, url

For example, I had this link for a comment plug-in: http://example.com/user_name/

But I have changed the URLs to: http://example.com/country_name/user_name/

How can I reconnect all previous comments to my new URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the data-href or href property of the plugin to the previous URL.  You can't migrate comments from one URL to another.

Comment: and am I going to lose all my data (prev comments) with these new URLs?